# Add indentation to whole paragraph using apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am trying to add indentation(of 3 tabs) to the whole paragraph using Apache poi. Here is the code that i have used to create indentation.

```
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class ApachePOIExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Create a new Word document
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

            // Create a paragraph
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

            // Create a run and add text to it
            XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.addTab();
            run.addTab();
            run.addTab();
            run.setText("A paragraph is a series of sentences that are organized and 
    coherent, and are all related to a single topic. Almost every piece of writing you do 
    that is longer than a few sentences should be organized into paragraphs. This is because 
    paragraphs show a reader where the subdivisions of an essay begin and end, and thus help 
    the reader see the organization of the essay and grasp its main points.");

        // Save the document to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("example.docx")) {
                document.write(fileOutputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the output that i got from the above code. The run.addTab() function is indenting only the first line of the paragraph as shown below.
[image: code output]

Is there any way in apache poi that i could have format like this?
[image]

Any help or insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75259180/how-to-implement-the-hanging-indent-in-word-document-with-apache-poi/75259685#75259685 -> [XWPFParagraph.setIndentFromLeft](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#setIndentFromLeft-int-) without `XWPFParagraph.setIndentationHanging`.

Comment: You are adding a Tab character in Word, similar to pressing the Tab key when in text. What you want to do is change the paragraph formatting to set a left indent.